# Accessing mySQL columns dynamically using PHP

Tags: php, dynamic

I pull a row out of the database and I want to access it via a dynamic var

```
$prop = "theProp";

$test0 = $row["theProp"]; // Works fine
$test1 = $row->{$prop}; // Doesn't work
$test2 = $row->$prop; // Doesn't work
```

I've looked all over the place, obviously doing something stupid, can someone enlighten me please.

Comment: Use `$row[$prop]` just like any other array. Why are you using `->`?

Answer (score 0):

You are so near, just replace `"theProp"` in `$row["theProp"]` with `$prop`.

So this should work:

```
$prop = "theProp";

$test3 = $row[$prop];
```

In your case, `$row` is an array, not an object, that's why `$row->$prop` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try casting the array as an object. The below works fine:

```
$array['one'] = "number 1, ";
$array['two'] = "number 2, ";

$object = (object) $array;

echo $object->one;
echo $object->two;



Output: number 1, number 2,
```

Comment: Thank you for all the responses, I was pretty sure I'd tried $row[$prop] (which I am very familiar with from other languages) and it didn't work which was why I ended up looking elsewhere as I'm not familiar in PHP. I must be going insane, as it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `fetch_object()`/`mysqli_fetch_object()` when you pull data from the database. Your `$row` is an array and not an object, which is why your code doesn't work.